# pass object back or pull from firebase

Tags: ios, firebase, swift3, firebase-realtime-database, conceptual

I have a situation where I am creating and saving objects to firebase. These can then be edited, and viewed in multiple places, or in multiple viewControllers.

I cannot decide if it is best to continually pass the whole object back and forth, so that when it is changed each view will get the most recent version.

Or, to only pass a little reference to it, or some way that each view knows which one it is dealing with, then have each view just download the most recent version from Firebase...

So central location for up/down from firebase, and pass the object locally around the App.

Or pass some reference around, and have each View up/down/observe with Firebase to stay up to date.

Does this make sense? Sorry for a very conceptual question and thank you for any input!

Comment: This is way to vague as there are multiple answers and they all depend on your use case. If you want other users to see changes, then you will need to keep sync'd with Firebase. If it's just one user, then load once, edit, write when done. As far as keeping the object (pic, string whatever) alive in your app there's a lot of ways to do that; anywhere from an old-school Singleton pattern (yeah yeah, don't go there) to keeping an app level variable in the app-delegate to passing with segues. I would suggest posting some code and reviewing [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I know this is super vague. Just thought maybe it would be easier rather than posting basically my whole project, to get some sort of general structural advice. That being said, as a new developer, I am often obsessed with finding "best practices", and this is just a reminder that every case is different. I am working out a solution now, and will ask again with code if I run into something more specific.